# Firebase notifications message with emojis in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, emoji

Has anyone used firebase_messaging to receive notifications with emojis?
I am receiving the data, for example Title with the unicode of the emoji \u1F603 (from page http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

```
{
 "notification": {
   "title" : "Titte with emoji \\u1F603 ",
...rest of code
```

but flutter does not convert it to the emoji in notifications bar.
I am using FirebaseMessaging libraries, as indicated on their website https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Comment: You can use direct emojis and it works in all the platforms. Why are using emoji codes?

Comment: I am using the firebase API: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
How could I send emojis in the json?

Comment: ok! That's a problem then. Sorry. But if you don't find any solution use cloud functions to send the notifications.

Comment: is there somewhere in firebase where i could do it? I did not find that, especially sending to users subscribed to a topic

Comment: https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/

Comment: thanks, I was able to find the topic targeting!
But I did not find option to insert emojis in notification Title

Comment: you can use hardcoded strings with emojis and send them from firebase functions.

Comment: Thanks, with your alternatives I came to find that I only have to make a copy of the emoji image and paste it in the console or in the json, it is not necessary to put the encode \uXXXX

Comment: Exactly!! Happy coding!